# ExpressJS - router module with parameters

Tags: node.js, express

I've been toying with NodeJS and Express for a few days, and it is pretty cool. But I've run into an issue I cannot get my head around, so I'm hoping someone else out there can help me clear this up.

I know that I can declare a module, and then pass parameters into this module via the `require` method.

```
--- App.js ----
var foo = require('./modules/Foo.js');
    foo.config();
var bar= {}
    require('./modules/Bar.js)(bar, foo)

--- Bar.js ---
module.exports = function(Bar, Foo) {
     Bar.act = function(){
          Foo.do();
     }
}
```

I think this is a much cleaner design than having to require `Foo` in every module that would require using it. I also don't have to do initialization in each module that requires it.

But then comes the `Router`, and I can't really understand how it works. Most examples out there requires the router in each module, something like this:

```
--- App.js ----
var index = require('./views/index.js');
app.use('/', index);

--- Index.js ---
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var foo = require('../modules/Foo.js);

foo.config();

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  foo.do();
  res.render('index');
})

module.exports = router
```

But then, I need to require all modules used in `index.js` manually. What I would really want to do is something like this:

```
--- App.js ----
var foo = require('../modules/Foo.js);
    foo.config();
var index = require('./views/index.js')(foo);
app.use('/', index);

--- Index.js ---
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

module.exports = function(foo){
    router.get('/', function (req, res) {
        foo.do();
        res.render('index');
    })
}
```

But writing it this way, the compiler tells me "Router.use() requires middleware, got a undefined". I can sorta see where this error comes from, (the `module.exports` does not return an object) but so how do I structure my code so that I can pass parameters to a module that in the end will export a Router middleware? I want to require and initialize `Foo` in one place, then pass it to all router modules that uses it. Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it, you just need to return the `Router`.

A fixed `index.js` could look like this:

```
var express = require('express');

module.exports = function(foo){
    var router = express.Router();

    router.get('/', function (req, res) {
        foo.do();
        res.render('index');
    });

    return router;
}
```

Notice the additional `;` and the return.

I've also moved the instantiation of the router to the function. In node modules are [cached](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching), you can require the same module multiple times and they will all share their global variables. This can lead to unexpected results. In your case you'll overwrite the `router.get` handler every time and the same instance of `Foo` would be used for every request.